# How to properly escape fulltext index query parameter in Spring Data Neo4j?

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

In a Spring Data Neo4j Repository I have a custom query defined as:

```
@Query(
    value = "CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('mimir_NorseDeity_label_fulltext', $label) YIELD node AS n RETURN n SKIP $skip LIMIT $limit",
    countQuery = "CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('mimir_NorseDeity_label_fulltext', $label) YIELD node AS COUNT(n)"
)
Page<NorseDeity> fulltextFindByLabel(@Param("label") String label, Pageable page);
```

But the `$label` parameter needs to be escaped for many special characters that are not supported in the Lucene query language.

How do I escape them without adding boilerplate to the Repository interface?